# Flying through starfield. LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

What is the best way to implement something like [this](http://p5ide.herokuapp.com/view/57b2dedd88b5ff030092c5f7) using LibGDX ? I have searched in the internet about this but didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: what about trying it yourself?

Comment: look up libGDX tutorial on google (or bing), learn it, then think your way through how to do that with your newfound knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While, you still need to think this through, I'll point you in the right direction, I would recommend you create an object with values such as a vector2 for the spawn point and a vector2 for the direction, as well as an integer for the time counter, I would update these variables in a render function within the object. Then create an array of this specific object and update each value in the game render function using a for loop, and in that loop render a line with a shape renderer of a length depending on the time passed, and in the direction of the vector. 
Also, if you liked this answer but would like further detail, check this as an answer and I'll edit in an example

Comment: That's great! I hope my answer helped!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I found a solition using Vector3, where x and y coordinates are randomly ganerated in (0, width/height) range and z in (depth_start, depth_end) range. Finally the velocity of each object times z value.